# MPI program runtime error MPI_GATHER, qsub mpijobparallel

Tags: runtime-error, mpi, mpich

I am trying to run this fast fourier implementation code. It compiles fine but gives this error at runtime. I have no idea about the error or what it means. Can anyone help me out?
I compiled and run the program by:

```
mpicc -o exec test.c
./exec
```

CODE:
This is the code that I found on GITHUB. Its the parallel version of fast fourier algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h> //To use MPI
#include <complex.h> //to use complex numbers
#include <math.h>   //for cos() and sin()
#include "timer.h" //to use timer

#define PI 3.14159265
#define bigN 16384 //Problem Size
#define howmanytimesavg 3 

int main()
{
int my_rank,comm_sz;
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); //start MPI
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&comm_sz);   ///how many processes are we 
using?
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_rank);   //which process is this?
double start,finish;
double avgtime = 0;
FILE *outfile;
int h;
if(my_rank == 0) //if process 0 open outfile
{
    outfile = fopen("ParallelVersionOutput.txt", "w"); //open from current 
directory
}
for(h = 0; h < howmanytimesavg; h++) //loop to run multiple times for AVG 
time.
{
    if(my_rank == 0) //If it's process 0 starts timer
    {   
        start = MPI_Wtime();
    }
    int i,k,n,j; //Basic loop variables

    double complex evenpart[(bigN / comm_sz / 2)]; //array to save the data 
for EVENHALF
    double complex oddpart[(bigN / comm_sz / 2)]; //array to save the data 
for ODDHALF
    double complex evenpartmaster[ (bigN / comm_sz / 2) * comm_sz]; //array 
to save the data for EVENHALF
    double complex oddpartmaster[ (bigN / comm_sz / 2) * comm_sz]; //array 
to save the data for ODDHALF
    double storeKsumreal[bigN]; //store the K real variable so we can abuse 
symmerty
    double storeKsumimag[bigN]; //store the K imaginary variable so we can 
abuse symmerty

    double subtable[(bigN / comm_sz)][3]; //Each process owns a subtable 
from the table below 

    double table[bigN][3] = //TABLE of numbers to use
                        {
                         0,3.6,2.6, //n, Real,Imaginary CREATES TABLE
                         1,2.9,6.3,
                         2,5.6,4.0,
                         3,4.8,9.1,
                         4,3.3,0.4,
                         5,5.9,4.8,
                         6,5.0,2.6,
                         7,4.3,4.1,
                         };
        if(bigN > 8)  //Everything after row 8 is all 0's
        {
            for(i = 8; i < bigN; i++)
            {
                table[i][0] = i;
                for(j = 1; j < 3;j++)
                {
                    table[i][j] = 0.0; //set to 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    int sendandrecvct = (bigN / comm_sz) * 3; //how much to send and 
recieve??
MPI_Scatter(table,sendandrecvct,MPI_DOUBLE,subtable,sendandrecvct,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); //scatter the table to subtables
    for (k = 0; k < bigN / 2; k++) //K coeffiencet Loop 
    {
                /* Variables used for the computation */
        double sumrealeven = 0.0; //sum of real numbers for even
        double sumimageven = 0.0; //sum of imaginary numbers for even
        double sumrealodd = 0.0; //sum of real numbers for odd
        double sumimagodd = 0.0; //sum of imaginary numbers for odd

        for(i = 0; i < (bigN/comm_sz)/2; i++) //Sigma loop EVEN and ODD
        {
            double factoreven , factorodd = 0.0;
            int shiftevenonnonzeroP = my_rank * subtable[2*i][0]; //used to shift index numbers for correct results for EVEN.
            int shiftoddonnonzeroP = my_rank * subtable[2*i + 1][0]; //used to shift index numbers for correct results for ODD.

            /* -------- EVEN PART -------- */
            double realeven = subtable[2*i][1]; //Access table for real number at spot 2i
            double complex imaginaryeven = subtable[2*i][2]; //Access table for imaginary number at spot 2i
            double complex componeeven = (realeven + imaginaryeven * I); //Create the first component from table
            if(my_rank == 0) //if proc 0, dont use shiftevenonnonzeroP
            {
                factoreven = ((2*PI)*((2*i)*k))/bigN; //Calculates the even factor for Cos() and Sin()                                      
                            //   *********Reduces computational time*********
            }
            else //use shiftevenonnonzeroP
            {
                factoreven = ((2*PI)*((shiftevenonnonzeroP)*k))/bigN; //Calculates the even factor for Cos() and Sin()                                      
                            //   *********Reduces computational time*********
            }
            double complex comptwoeven = (cos(factoreven) - (sin(factoreven)*I)); //Create the second component

            evenpart[i] = (componeeven * comptwoeven); //store in the evenpart array

            /* -------- ODD PART -------- */
            double realodd = subtable[2*i + 1][1]; //Access table for real number at spot 2i+1
            double complex imaginaryodd = subtable[2*i + 1][2]; //Access table for imaginary number at spot 2i+1
            double complex componeodd = (realodd + imaginaryodd * I); //Create the first component from table
            if (my_rank == 0)//if proc 0, dont use shiftoddonnonzeroP
            {
                factorodd = ((2*PI)*((2*i+1)*k))/bigN;//Calculates the odd factor for Cos() and Sin()                                       
                            // *********Reduces computational time********* 
            }
            else //use shiftoddonnonzeroP
            {
                factorodd = ((2*PI)*((shiftoddonnonzeroP)*k))/bigN;//Calculates the odd factor for Cos() and Sin()                                      
                            // *********Reduces computational time*********
            }

            double complex comptwoodd = (cos(factorodd) - (sin(factorodd)*I));//Create the second component

            oddpart[i] = (componeodd * comptwoodd); //store in the oddpart array

        }
        /*Process ZERO gathers the even and odd part arrays and creates a evenpartmaster and oddpartmaster array*/
        MPI_Gather(evenpart,(bigN / comm_sz / 2),MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,evenpartmaster,(bigN / comm_sz / 2), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Gather(oddpart,(bigN / comm_sz / 2),MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,oddpartmaster,(bigN / comm_sz / 2), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        if(my_rank == 0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < (bigN / comm_sz / 2) * comm_sz; i++) //loop to sum the EVEN and ODD parts
            {
                sumrealeven += creal(evenpartmaster[i]); //sums the realpart of the even half
                sumimageven += cimag(evenpartmaster[i]); //sums the imaginarypart of the even half
                sumrealodd += creal(oddpartmaster[i]); //sums the realpart of the odd half
                sumimagodd += cimag(oddpartmaster[i]); //sums the imaginary part of the odd half
            }
            storeKsumreal[k] = sumrealeven + sumrealodd; //add the calculated reals from even and odd
            storeKsumimag[k]  = sumimageven + sumimagodd; //add the calculated imaginary from even and odd
            storeKsumreal[k + bigN/2] = sumrealeven - sumrealodd; //ABUSE symmetry Xkreal + N/2 = Evenk - OddK
            storeKsumimag[k + bigN/2] = sumimageven - sumimagodd; //ABUSE symmetry Xkimag + N/2 = Evenk - OddK
            if(k <= 10) //Do the first 10 K's
            {
                if(k == 0)
                {
                    fprintf(outfile," \n\n TOTAL PROCESSED SAMPLES : %d\n",bigN);
                }
                fprintf(outfile,"================================\n");
                fprintf(outfile,"XR[%d]: %.4f XI[%d]: %.4f \n",k,storeKsumreal[k],k,storeKsumimag[k]);
                fprintf(outfile,"================================\n");
            }
        }
    }
    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        GET_TIME(finish); //stop timer
        double timeElapsed = finish-start; //Time for that iteration
        avgtime = avgtime + timeElapsed; //AVG the time 
        fprintf(outfile,"Time Elaspsed on Iteration %d: %f Seconds\n", (h+1),timeElapsed);
    }
}
if(my_rank == 0)
{
    avgtime = avgtime / howmanytimesavg; //get avg time
    fprintf(outfile,"\nAverage Time Elaspsed: %f Seconds", avgtime);
    fclose(outfile); //CLOSE file ONLY proc 0 can.
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); //wait to all proccesses to catch up before finalize
MPI_Finalize(); //End MPI
return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Gather: Invalid datatype, error stack:
PMPI_Gather(904): MPI_Gather(sbuf=0x7fffb62799a0, scount=8192, 
MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, rbuf=0x7fffb6239980, rcount=8192, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, 
root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
PMPI_Gather(815): Datatype for argument sendtype is a null datatype
[unset]: write_line error; fd=-1 buf=:cmd=abort exitcode=537490947
:
system msg for write_line failure : Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: So you have copied a wall of code and expect others to get it working for you?

Comment: Can you help me understand the error only then?

Comment: Why don't you use mpirun to run that program? Any MPI program must be run with mpirun command, where you can also specify the number of processes that are available to that MPI program.

Comment: strictly speaking, Open MPI has a singleton mode in which it is legit to directly run the MPI app without `mpirun`. I guess MPICH has such feature too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `MPI_DATATYPE_NULL` in your code, but you only use `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX`. Note the latter type is a `Fortran` datatype, and using it in `C` is not correct strictly speaking.

My guess is that `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` is causing the issue (type not defined or not initialized because you invoked the `C` version of `MPI_Init()`).

You can obviously rewrite your code in Fortran, or use your own derived datatype for a `C` double complex number.

Meanwhile, I suggest you write simple `C` and `Fortran` helloworld programs that use `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` (`MPI_Bcast()` of one element for example) to confirm the issue is with `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` and is restricted to `C` or not.

Comment: Thanks. I found the error. The datatype should be MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX and that's it. Thanks a lot.